# Monitorin datasource health in Tomcat server using JMX console

Tags: wso2, tomcat7, jmx, jmx-ws

I am using Tomcat 7.0. I have deployed a Java-based application in it. I want to monitor application datasources health using JMX console. But, I must be missing something, because I have enabled JMX and connected to it, but I'm still unable to get the datasource details.

Same question goes about monitoring in `wso2esb`.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2, the custom datasources monitoring via JMX is not yet available. This is fixed in current master branch and it will be available in future versions.

Please check the WSO2 Carbon JIRA: [CARBON-15172](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15172).

For Tomcat, if you use [JNDI datasources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) managed via Tomcat Container, you will be able to see the [JNDI datasources via JMX](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring#JNDI_DataSource). If you are using Tomcat JDBC Pool outside the container, you will have to [register the JDBC Pool with JMX](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JMX).